# InAppBrowser clipboard context menu doesn't show up on Android

Tags: android, contextmenu, inappbrowser

I'm using Ionic for building a multi-platform hybrid app that, basically, just opens a responsive web app, with `InAppBrowser` plugin. I can't figure out why, only on Android (on iOS it works as expected), the standard context menu, for copy/paste operation, after a long click on input text, doesn't appear, only the markers for the select text are displayed.

I can't find out what I'm missing, did it suppose to show up by default, on Android, or did I need some configuration, register some listener, use other plugin or whatever?

So, in short, if I copy some text on a device (e.g. from **google.com**) and I want to be able to paste it, on Android, in an input text, of a page opened with InAppBrowser within my app, is it possible and how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that the standard behavior, even with `InAppBrowser`, is to display the context menu, to manage copy/paste operation, on long click, on the selectable text.

So, in my case, it wasn't an `InAppBrowser` problem, but it was the site who disable all context menu (iOS just doesn't care and show it anyway, but that's another story).